# Angular unit test failed for [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, angular2-template

My angular2 unit test code fails with the below traceback. I know it's because of not adding `formControlName` attribute to the `input` tag which was inside a FormGroup.

But I added `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` to that particular tag.

```
<md-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isAvailable" color="primary" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</md-slide-toggle>
```

It works perfectly in the main site but on testing, it shows

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 39 of 65 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 1.391 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) VehicleFormComponent should create FAILED
    Error: Error in ./VehicleFormComponent class VehicleFormComponent - inline template:41:63 caused by: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute in src/test.ts (line 98781)
    _throwError@webpack:///~/@angular/forms/src/directives/shared.js:122:0 <- src/test.ts:15986:48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, the error you are getting if you have not specified

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}
```

is the following:

[image]

So the other option is to set a `name` attribute. Your current error:

`... form control with unspecified name attribute...`

seems to be very similar to the error in the above picture. **IF** it doesn't matter if you are using `ngModelOptions` or the `name` attribute, you could try to remove `ngModelOptions` and insert the `name` instead. Functionally this doesn't change the execution of your code in any way, therefore it is a very viable option in my opinion (***If*** it works)

Comment: I set name attribute like `<md-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isAvailable" color="primary" name="isAvaialble">` but it shows like `no form control associated with the name isAvaiable`. At last I replace `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` with `ngDefaultControl` and it works.

Comment: Well great that you figured it out! :)